# Chain rxMethods with NGRX & signals

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals, ngrx

The Ngrx last update offers support for Angular signals.

I’m looking for a way to **chain rxMethods with NGRX & signals**.

Firstly I thought of chaining them directly in the store statement.

However I was not able to figure out how this can be done, nor if it’s the right thing to do.

I would be grateful if someone knows how to perform such synchronous calls.

```
export const BookStore = signalStore(
    {providedIn: 'root'},
    withState(initialState),
    withMethods((store, bookService = inject(BookService)) => ({
        loadRandomAuthor: rxMethod<number>(
            pipe(
                switchMap(() => {
                    return bookService.getRandomAuthor().pipe(
                        tap({
                            next: (author: Author) => {
                                patchState(store, {author});
                                //  call loadBooksByAuthorId method with author.id here
                            },
                        })
                    );
                })
            )
        ),
        //  here is the method to be synchronously called
        loadBooksByAuthorId: rxMethod<number>(
            pipe(
                switchMap((authorId: number) => {
                    return bookService.getBooksByAuthorId(authorId).pipe(
                        tap({
                            next: (books: Book[]) => {
                                patchState(store, {books});
                            },
                        })
                    );
                })
            )
        )
    }))
);
```

Comment: "chain synchronous http calls" there's no such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests are asynchronous. What you meant is consequent.

Calling one effect from another is a code smell.

I recommend this way: `loadRandomAuthor()` should set `authorId` in the state, and `loadBooksByAuthorId()` should observe `authorId` in the state and load books when that id is changed.

Your `loadRandomAuthor()` already sets `author`, so `loadBooksByAuthorId()` should observe `state.author.id`.

Comment: Thank you for you input. However I was not able to set the behavior you describe but I'm still trying

Comment: @Maxime I've create a stackBlitz for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ijjlyj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

To access the loadBooksByAuthorId() method, you can simply declare another withMethods() under the existing one and implement the loadRandomAuthor() method inside it. In this case, your store will already have the loadBooksByAuthorId() method and you can call it from the second withMethods().

But there is another option.
Take a look at this solution: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/4182